# How can I stop loading wordpress jquery on header?

Tags: javascript

How to remove wordpress jquery to footer.

Looks like all scripts are wordpress's core script and there must be some way to remove and move to footer. Please guide.

Also Jquery is not moving to footer. Here is the code:

```
function jquery_mv_footer()
{
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery-core');
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery-migrate');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', false, array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-core', false, array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-migrate', false, array(), false, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_mv_footer');
```

Comment: Why Negative? I am unable to find the hook name for these and so cant unhook it via theme function.

Comment: WordPress uses dependencies, you should look at all queued scripts. One of them will require jQuery, so WP loads jQuery etc pp.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see last section on jquery moving to footer

Comment: Don't put multiple questions into one, that just clutters it up. If you have multiple questions, create multiple separate questions.

Comment: edited my question and I really apologize for the confusion and mult question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin, there are few or deregister script in function

> ```
> wp_deregister_script( 'scriptname' );
> ```

But your blog will stop loading.corectlly  because you need them.

Comment: That I know. Please see my question . I have edited now.

Comment: I edited answer also